# How to increase the validation accuracy in Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to create a machine learning in ANN to predict a Multiclass Classification problem. The validation accuracy was stucked somewehere around 0.4 to 0.5 but the training accuracy was high and increasing along the epochs.

The dataset looks like this:

```
project_type_id_Apartemen   project_type_id_Bandara project_type_id_Dam Weir    project_type_id_Hotel   project_type_id_Industry Petrochemical  project_type_id_Irigasi project_type_id_Jalan Jembatan  project_type_id_Komersil    project_type_id_Lain-lain   project_type_id_Oil Gas ... area_ASA    area_BALI&NUSA TENGGARA area_JAKARTA    area_JAWA   area_KALIMANTAN area_MALUKU area_PAPUA  area_SULAWESI   area_SUMATERA   area_TIMORLESTE
174 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   ... 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
133 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
326 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
473 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
55  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
71  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
106 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
270 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
435 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
102 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

Here is my model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(37,input_dim=37,activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    keras.layers.Dense(30,activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    keras.layers.Dense(20,activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train,
          validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
          batch_size=128,epochs=2500)
```

This is the output:

```
Epoch 844/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 30ms/step - loss: 0.2595 - accuracy: 0.8766 - val_loss: 3.1100 - val_accuracy: 0.4277
Epoch 845/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: 0.2657 - accuracy: 0.8924 - val_loss: 3.1053 - val_accuracy: 0.4214
Epoch 846/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 0.2840 - accuracy: 0.8671 - val_loss: 3.0908 - val_accuracy: 0.4277
Epoch 847/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2639 - accuracy: 0.8987 - val_loss: 3.0742 - val_accuracy: 0.4403
Epoch 848/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 0.3026 - accuracy: 0.8718 - val_loss: 3.0469 - val_accuracy: 0.4403
Epoch 849/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 0.2802 - accuracy: 0.8845 - val_loss: 3.0113 - val_accuracy: 0.4528
Epoch 850/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 0.2614 - accuracy: 0.8892 - val_loss: 2.9987 - val_accuracy: 0.4528
Epoch 851/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 0.2593 - accuracy: 0.8940 - val_loss: 2.9887 - val_accuracy: 0.4403
Epoch 852/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 0.2260 - accuracy: 0.9161 - val_loss: 3.0022 - val_accuracy: 0.4403
Epoch 853/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: 0.2669 - accuracy: 0.8845 - val_loss: 3.0241 - val_accuracy: 0.4654
Epoch 854/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 52ms/step - loss: 0.2913 - accuracy: 0.8703 - val_loss: 3.0524 - val_accuracy: 0.4277
Epoch 855/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 51ms/step - loss: 0.2261 - accuracy: 0.9019 - val_loss: 3.0725 - val_accuracy: 0.4340
Epoch 856/2500
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 46ms/step - loss: 0.2658 - accuracy: 0.8813 - val_loss: 3.0963 - val_accuracy: 0.4340
```

Comment: Three classes, you're getting 0.44, or slightly better than 1/num_of_classes, which is 1/3 or 0.33, and loss is barely changing, yet training metrics are fine. Either your model is severely overfitting, or you're shuffling your validation data. Only shuffle your training set, unless you can shuffle the features and labels of the validation/test set while keeping track of labels (hint: this is not usually done by default, so it's easiest to just not shuffle at all). If you don't know whether you're shuffling your dataset or not, please update your question with how you defined your datasets.

Comment: 1. From the trend of your loss, you may have used a too large learning rate or large dropouts. 2. Your first layer has 37 units. It does not need to be the same size as your features. You may want to consider 64, or maybe 128 (or even larger depending on the number of examples in your dataset). 3. Start without dropout aiming at finding a model that fits well your training dataset. 4. You will then most likely see some overfitting problem, then try to add regulizers like dropout to mitigate the issue.

Comment: I have already tried to not shuffle at all by defining the shuffle parameter to False. But nothing happens.

Comment: There are a lot of things that can be causing this problem, Given the very low validation accuracy and no real improvement in validation loss I suspect you are doing something to mess up the relationship between the validation data and its associated labels. Please show code you used to generate validation data.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is obviously overfitting. The most common cause is that the model has too many parameters which allows it to fit perfectly to training data but in doing so it loses the ability to generalise.

Then I'd reduce the number of trainable parameters in the model. Start with removing some of the `Dense` layers. This will result in training accuracy to take a dip, but hopefully will result in test accuracy going up.

You can then start adding layers until you have a balanced model with ideally training and test accuracies close to one another. Usually, train accuracy should be somewhat higher.

I'd start over with this model with just one hidden layer and one output layer:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(37,input_dim=37,activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax')
```

And then build up from there.

Comment: I tried the Dropout start with 0.1, after increasing the Dropout number to 0.5, the validation accuracy is higher but the training accuracy became lower

Comment: The training accuracy should decrease because the current accuracy of around 90% doesn't reflect the ability of the model to predict on the new data. With almost any ML model you can get training accuracy to close to 100% so training accuracy is not that important, it's the balance between train/test.

Comment: agree with @pavel. A common mistake of new practitioner is crafting a complex model at start then struggle with self-created problems e.g. code bug and low accuracy. Always starts simple and build up. In your case, I may even start from a simple logistic regression model.